# jquery opening a link with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using a third party payment system that opens up a small popup that allows the user to enter their details.

I can see that they are using fancybox but cannot edit their js or css.

I have a current setup that uses jquery that creates steps that guide the user through the various payment options and platforms i use.

At the moment the other payment platforms being used open a new page. I want this one platform to open the fancybox. I am able to link to it with jquery (it switches the link based on the amount).

My issue is that I need to inlude a class thats normally in the  tags, using location.href I cant seem to keep this class which opens the overlay rather than a new window.

so currently:

```
r += (r.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'amount=' + $('#plus_amount').val()
location.href = r;
```

Opens as new page

What i need:

```
<a class="payment-widget" href="payment link">
```

Is there any way to open a link with jquery and have it use a class as well?

Thanks in advance

Nad

Comment: the class adds css features to your dom elements and only, nothing more. If you want the opened link to have some class (like a sir!) then you should define a style at that page.

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης : well, you can use the class selector to manipulate the DOM element via jQuery (including removing the element or triggering a `click` on it for instance) apart from adding css features "only"

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you mean by "open a link using a class", but you can open fancybox manually instead of using `location.href`:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    href : r,
    title : 'Title'
},{
    //options
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HK29L/

Or if you want to assign the href to the anchor:

```
$('.payment-widget').attr('href', r);
```

(and then you can trigger a click if you like).